# What's wrong with the Alter Column Statement in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, ddl

This is driving me crazy. I don't know whats wrong with this query?

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `mydb.persons` MODIFY COLUMN `name` VARCHAR;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: Are you using back ticks or single quotes?

Comment: FWIW: \`mydb.persons\` should be \`mydb\`.\`persons\`, or just mydb.persons -- see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html: "If any components of a multiple-part name require quoting, *quote [components] individually..*"

Comment: you need to define a length for `VARCHAR` column such as `VARCHAR(50)`

Answer (score 0):

The information included in the quotes in the `...the right syntax to use near '...'` error message is *the unexpected thing* the parser encountered.  When it is an empty string `''` then this means the error is a premature end to the query -- every thing up to the end was parsed without a problem, but the query can't possibly end where it did, and still be valid.  A more obvious example would be the query `SELECT * FROM;` which would return exactly the same error.  (The trailing semicolon, if present, has already been discarded at this point, so it doesn't appear in this error message.)

The `VARCHAR` data type requires that you specify a maximum character length for the column, in parentheses.  For example, if you wanted a column with a maximum length of 96 characters:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `mydb.persons` MODIFY COLUMN `name` VARCHAR(96);
```

> The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, `CHAR(30)` can hold up to 30 characters.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html